# Discord.py Bot that doesn't act like it has permissions

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So I am working on a Discord Bot and trying to work on role assignments. I made sure that I am using the new rewrite system, I made sure I gave the bot administrative privileges. I have taken just about every measure I could think of and it simply is not working. I looked at the updated API to handle it, used sample code as a framework,  This is the code

```
import os

import discord
from discord.utils import get as dget
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('key.env')
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected')

@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Sample")
    await user.add_roles(role)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

and this is the error that i get:

```
Ignoring exception in command role:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:/Google Drive/Coding/Khasbot/main.py", line 22, in role
    await user.add_roles(role)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 641, in add_roles        
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 221, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke 
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

I honestly have no idea what could be going wrong. I have tried endless things and even created a whole new bot altogether. Still the same issue. It worked last night and literally just won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your bot **must** have Manage Roles permission on your server and the role for adding roles **must** be lower than your bot top role.
Make you did these 2 things.

Comment: I did confirm both of these things and I am still having the same problem. I also have an admin role that I also add to the bot

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't realize I had to drag it to the top

Comment: @gospelguy2004 Please make sure to mark my question as the correct one.